# command builder update doesn't work

Tags: c#, datagrid, mysql

Code seems to be fine but when i click it, nothing happens. 
THanks!

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from poitems", coninsert);
        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "poitems");
        da.Update(ds, "poitems");
        //DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        //da.Fill(dt1);
        //da.Update(dt1);


        //dtgPo.DataSource = dt1;
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code line by line? Are you sure your `da` has rows? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response sir. TO answer your question, yes i did insert 3 records for testing.

Answer (score 0):

you are not updating anything in your dataset, check below sample update code

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Test", conn);
MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da, true);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
//update datatable
dt.Rows[0][0] = "my changed value";
DataTable changes = dt.GetChanges();
//call update 
da.Update(changes);
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I really appreciate it and I'm checking it now.

Comment: sir i got this error code: The name 'Da' does not exist in the current context. Also, as an additional inquiry,to t what values should i put in the "my chaged value"? Im kinda new to c#. Thanks!